# Characterization of continuity in terms of preimages of open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity

> 1--8 Theorem. If $A\subset \mathbb R^n$, a function $f:A\to \mathbb  R^m$ is continuous if and only if for every open set $U\subset \mathbb R^m$ there is some open set $V\subset \mathbb  R^n$ such that $f^{-1}(U) = V\cap A$.

I want to prove this theorem , but i can't understand it even for $n=1$ and $m=1$. I can't see how can  a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be  discontinuous if this theorem is true , 
since we can just take $V = \{0\}$ and then $f^{-1}(U)=\{0\}$ doesn't exist

Take $n=1$ and $m=1$ , and lets define $f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ define by  $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if } x<2\\ x^2& \text{if }x\geq 2\end{cases}$$
I can't prove that this function isn't continious on $\mathbb R$. 
Take the open set $U=]3,3+\frac12[$ , then there is $V=\{0\}$ , such that $f^{-1}(U)=\{0\}$

Comment: That function is discontinuous because the inverse image of $(3,9)$ is $[2,3)$, which is not open.

Comment: What definition of continuity are you working with? Without knowing that, it's hard to address how a proof would work. Is it an epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: In other words, show that the preimage is open in $A$. You can find this in any book in analysis no?

Comment: Your arguments are not clear ! The three first line has totally no sens !! What is $U$ ? For your exemple, $V$ is close, not open !! What do you want to say ? Moreover this theorem is in fact the definition of continuity.

Comment: If $U=\varnothing$, then $f^{-1}(U)=V\cap A$ -- just take $V=\varnothing$ as well.

Comment: The choice of $V$ depends on $U$ (and $f$), so you are just not picking $V$ well.

Comment: To me it is obvious that you reading Spivak's Cakculus on Manifolds, although you do not explicitly say so. What exactly is your background in real analysis? Do you know what a metric space is?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $(Y,d|Y\times Y)$ is a subspace of the metric space $(X,d)$, then a set $O'\subseteq Y$ is open (in $Y$) if and only if there exists an open set $O\subseteq X$ such that $O' = O \cap Y$.

The "only if" direction can be proven by considering a set of open balls (in $Y$) $C_\alpha\subseteq O'$, where $\alpha\in C_\alpha$ ($\bigcup_{\alpha\in O'} C_\alpha = O'$); let $B_\alpha$ be the open ball in $X$ with the same radius and center as $C_\alpha$, so that $B_\alpha \cap Y = C_\alpha$.
Then, $O' = \bigcup_{\alpha\in O'} (B_\alpha\cap Y) =(\bigcup_{\alpha\in O'} B_\alpha)\cap Y$, so $O = \bigcup_{\alpha\in O'} B_\alpha$ works.

On the other hand, if $O' = O\cap Y$ for some open $O$ (in $X$), then let $O = \bigcup_{\alpha\in O} D_\alpha$ for open balls $D_\alpha$ containing $\alpha$.
Then, $D_\alpha \cap Y$ is an open ball (in $Y$), and $\bigcup_{\alpha\in O} (D_\alpha\cap Y) =(\bigcup_{\alpha\in O} D_\alpha)\cap Y = O'$; $O'$ is a union of open balls and thus is open.

Thus, what this theorem reduces to is the fact that $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of each open set of the codomain is an open set of $A$, which is a standard definition of continuity.

Also, as a sidenote, see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) to learn how to make your equations look prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}x & \text{if $x<2$} \\ x^2 & \text{if $x\geq 2$}\end{array}\right.$$
We consider the open set $(1.5\,,3)\subset\mathbb R$ and notice that
$$f^{-1}(1.5\,,3) = f^{-1}[(1.5\,,2)\cup[2,3)]=f^{-1}(1.5\,,2)\cup f^{-1}[2,3)=(1.5\,,2)\cup [\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)=[\sqrt 2,2)$$
as $[\sqrt 2,2)$ is not a open set in $\mathbb R$ with usual topology, then $f$ is not continuous. According to theorem, in this case, there is no such open set $V\subset\mathbb R$ such that $[\sqrt 2,2)=V\cap\mathbb R$ (Note that, with the notations of the theorem, we have $A=\mathbb R$ and $U=(1.5\,,3)$).